# Python: Unit Test That Asserts Custom Exception Is Raised Fails When Try-Except Is Involved

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to write a unit test that asserts that my nested custom exception is raised by a function.

The below sample code passes:

```
from unittest import TestCase


class MyClass():
    class MyException(Exception):
        pass


def fail():
    raise MyClass.MyException()


class MyTests(TestCase):
    def test_throwsException(self):
        with self.assertRaises(MyClass.MyException):
            fail()
```

However, when my raising code involves a try-except, my test fails:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from enum import Enum


class Weekdays(Enum):
    MONDAY = 'mon'
    TUESDAY = 'tue'
    WEDNESDAY = 'wed'        
    THURSDAY = 'thu'        
    FRIDAY = 'fri'        

    class InvalidValue(Exception):
        pass


def parse(key: str) -> Weekdays:
    try:
        return Weekdays(key)
    except Exception as e:
        raise Weekdays.InvalidValue() from e


class MyTests(TestCase):
    def test_throwsException(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Weekdays.InvalidValue):
            parse('invalid')
```

It returns the below error:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_throwsException (test_main.MyTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\PythonCodes\playground\test_main.py", line 25, in test_throwsException
    with self.assertRaises(Weekdays.InvalidValue):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\unittest\case.py", line 816, in assertRaises
    return context.handle('assertRaises', args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\unittest\case.py", line 187, in handle
    raise TypeError('%s() arg 1 must be %s' %
TypeError: assertRaises() arg 1 must be an exception type or tuple of exception types

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I don't quite understand what `arg 1 must be an exception type` means because I assume that my custom exception ***is*** an exception type.

Why is the second version with the try-except failing?

Comment: Why are you defining your exception class *inside* your enum? This makes what you access from `Weekdays.InvalidValue` **an enum** with a `.value` of that class attribute... just like any other class attribute you define on your enum. Just remove it from the enum.

Comment: Hmm, I see! This has indeed resolved the issue. It seems that enum classes cannot have nested classes within them. Could you add this as an answer so I can accept it? By the way, I nested my custom exception for organization purposes.

Comment: Well, they *can*. But nesting a class isn't anything special, it's equivalent to `my_attribute = SomeClass`. In general, nesting classes is not a common pattern in Python. It really doesn't provide much of an advantage. The basic unit of code organization is the *module*.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll make note of that. Could you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: I've seen a few questions recently with nested classes in python. I think there is a common misconception of how nested classes work, in that they don't inherit anything at all from the class they're inside of. Maybe someone can correct me on this, but the only benefit I can see of nesting classes is organizing namespace. Then when the outer class changes how attribute access works, even that can go out the window.

Comment: @Aaron yes, that is the *only* effect sticking a class definition in another class definition's body is that the resulting class object lives in the namespace of the class it was nested in. Of course, with metaclasses, all sorts of chicanery can occur, as seen above. I've used nested classes once or twice, and I believe, they are used in Django (which relies heavily on metaclass magic). But it is almost always more trouble than it is worth. If a class is "private" and shouldn't exposed, just put it in the module level and use a single-underscore, this is the Pythonic convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've nested the definition of your exception class inside an enum:

```
class Weekdays(Enum):
    MONDAY = 'mon'
    TUESDAY = 'tue'
    WEDNESDAY = 'wed'        
    THURSDAY = 'thu'        
    FRIDAY = 'fri'        

    class InvalidValue(Exception):
        pass
```

enum's (through metaclass chicanery) make their class attributes *singleton instances of the enum class*, with the value you assigned to the attribute in the definition inside the `.value` of that enum instance. Just like the other class attributes you defined in your enum. So, consider:

```
In [1]: from enum import Enum

In [2]:
   ...: class Weekdays(Enum):
   ...:     MONDAY = 'mon'
   ...:     TUESDAY = 'tue'
   ...:     WEDNESDAY = 'wed'
   ...:     THURSDAY = 'thu'
   ...:     FRIDAY = 'fri'
   ...:
   ...:     class InvalidValue(Exception):
   ...:         pass
   ...:

In [3]: Weekdays.MONDAY
Out[3]: <Weekdays.MONDAY: 'mon'>

In [4]: Weekdays.MONDAY.value
Out[4]: 'mon'

In [5]: Weekdays.InvalidValue
Out[5]: <Weekdays.InvalidValue: <class '__main__.Weekdays.InvalidValue'>>

In [6]: Weekdays.InvalidValue.value
Out[6]: __main__.Weekdays.InvalidValue
```

So, you could use:

```
with self.assertRaises(Weekdays.InvalidValue.value):
    ...
```

And in similarly, in `parse`, you need:

```
raise Weekdays.InvalidValue.value() from e
```

But you are better off just defining `InvalidValue` at the module level.